# unattended-upgrades is not running

Tags: debian, apt, unattended-upgrades

I have a Debian 10 server on which unattended upgrades do not work.
The system timers are overwritten as follows:

`/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf`:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-* 13:30
RandomizedDelaySec=300
```

`/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.d/override.conf`

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-* 13:40
RandomizedDelaySec=300
```

The timers seems to run:

```
NEXT                          LEFT     LAST                          PASSED      UNIT                    ACTIVATES
Thu 2020-10-08 13:33:52 CEST  23h left Wed 2020-10-07 13:31:17 CEST  15min ago   apt-daily.timer         apt-daily.service
Thu 2020-10-08 13:40:55 CEST  23h left Wed 2020-10-07 13:43:20 CEST  3min 7s ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

But unattended-upgrades is not running.
If I run `unattended-upgrades -d` manual it's working fine.